# Correcting a wrong name on a FIDE ID

Tags: fide

My child is a new member of FIDE. However, his name is wrong. As such, I need to correct the name FIDE have for them.

How does one go about doing this?

Answer (score 5):

You need to contact your national federation and ask them to initiate the change for you. FIDE deals with member federations rather than individual members.

The person in your federation who is responsible for these things is the IRO (International Ratings Officer). You can find your IRO's contact details via the FIDE website. Go to the [FIDE Directory](https://ratings.fide.com/fide_directory.phtml) page, click on "Member Federations" and a list will appear grouped by continent. Find your federation and click on the link and you will see the details for your federation. For instance, the English federation is [here](https://ratings.fide.com/fide_directory.phtml?country=ENG&list=833) and the US federation is [here](https://ratings.fide.com/fide_directory.phtml?country=USA&list=931).